# Using Moment.Js with MVC/.NET Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, momentjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use moment js's `fromNow` function with a razor view on a C# `DateTime` object.

Coming from the Node/JavaScript world with view engines, I'd just do something like this:

```
p.card-text Last active: #{moment(user.lastLogin).fromNow()}
```

I'm not getting the syntax correct in the C#/.NET razor page world. I have the following, but not sure how I call moment and pass in the `@item.CreatedAt` argument to the moment.js `.fromNow()` method.

```
<small class="text-muted ml-auto">@item.CreatedAt</small>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `DateTime` you can try this:

```
<small>
<script>
document.write(moment('@item.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")').fromNow())
</script>
</small>
```